# how to change the char array to NSString

Tags: iphone, nsstring

for example I have a char array :

```
char array[8];
```

i tried:

```
NSString *marketPacket = [NSString stringWithCString:array encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",marketPacket);
```

but displays corrupted characters

Comment: For anyone else coming here and confused by the answers: the OP didn't have an * before `marketPacket` in the original version of this question, but changed it later making the whole question pointless.

Comment: Also, this is the first Google result for "nsstring from char array"

Comment: No idea why this was closed. Too localised?

Answer (score 14):

```
char array[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '\0'};
NSString *marketPacket = [NSString stringWithCString:array encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", marketPacket);
```

NSString is a class and you create an instance of it, so you have to put a * .
If you create an array, just populate it to see something..

Answer (score 0):

Change to

`NSString *marketPacket`

Should have given you a compiler error, actually. Strange. At least, assuming you copied and pasted the code, you need a pointer to NSString (as it is a Managed Object).